Markmap SVG as featured image in wordpress?
I'm trying to get a SVG file generated by the markmap library to work as a featured image on a post in wordpress.


(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const {
      markmap: O,
      mm: h
    } = window, M = new O.Toolbar;
    M.attach(h);
    const re = M.render();
    re.setAttribute("style", "position:absolute;bottom:20px;right:20px"), document.body.append(re)
  })
})();


((i, L, f, o) => {
  const w = i();
  window.mm = w.Markmap.create("svg#mindmap", (L || w.deriveOptions)(o), f)
})(() => window.markmap, null, {
  "content": "test",
  "children": [{
    "content": "Step1",
    "children": [],
    "payload": {
      "lines": "0,1"
    }
  }, {
    "content": "1step",
    "children": [{
      "content": "Step2",
      "children": [{
        "content": "2step",
        "children": [],
        "payload": {
          "lines": "3,4"
        }
      }, {
        "content": "Step3",
        "children": [],
        "payload": {
          "lines": "4,5"
        }
      }],
      "payload": {
        "lines": "2,5"
      }
    }],
    "payload": {
      "lines": "1,5"
    }
  }],
  "payload": {
    "lines": "0,5"
  }
}, {
  "colorFreezeLevel": 3
});
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mindmap {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/markmap-toolbar@0.17.0/dist/style.css">
<svg id="mindmap"></svg>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3@7.8.5/dist/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/markmap-view@0.17.0/dist/browser/index.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/markmap-toolbar@0.17.0/dist/index.js"></script>



SVG File code
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="w-screen h-screen leading-none markmap mm-1hipio-1" style=""><style>.markmap{--markmap-max-width: none;--markmap-a-color: #0097e6;--markmap-a-hover-color: #00a8ff;--markmap-code-bg: #f0f0f0;--markmap-code-color: #555;--markmap-highlight-bg: #ffeaa7;--markmap-table-border: 1px solid currentColor;--markmap-font: 300 16px/20px sans-serif;--markmap-circle-open-bg: #fff;--markmap-text-color: #333;font:var(--markmap-font);color:var(--markmap-text-color)}.markmap-link{fill:none}.markmap-node&gt;circle{cursor:pointer}.markmap-foreign{display:inline-block}.markmap-foreign p{margin:0}.markmap-foreign a{color:var(--markmap-a-color)}.markmap-foreign a:hover{color:var(--markmap-a-hover-color)}.markmap-foreign code{padding:.25em;font-size:calc(1em - 2px);color:var(--markmap-code-color);background-color:var(--markmap-code-bg);border-radius:2px}.markmap-foreign pre{margin:0}.markmap-foreign pre&gt;code{display:block}.markmap-foreign del{text-decoration:line-through}.markmap-foreign em{font-style:italic}.markmap-foreign strong{font-weight:700}.markmap-foreign mark{background:var(--markmap-highlight-bg)}.markmap-foreign table,.markmap-foreign th,.markmap-foreign td{border-collapse:collapse;border:var(--markmap-table-border)}.markmap-foreign img{display:inline-block}.markmap-foreign svg{fill:currentColor}.markmap-foreign-testing-max{max-width:var(--markmap-max-width)}.markmap-foreign-testing-max img{max-width:var(--markmap-max-width);max-height:none}.markmap-dark .markmap{--markmap-code-bg: #1a1b26;--markmap-code-color: #ddd;--markmap-circle-open-bg: #444;--markmap-text-color: #eee}</style><g transform="translate(210.7243977599602,257.94914047844014) scale(0.5152823188946778)"><path class="markmap-link" data-depth="2" data-path="1.2" d="M43,10C83,10,83,-5,123,-5" stroke="rgb(255, 127, 14)" stroke-width="1.5"></path><path class="markmap-link" data-depth="2" data-path="1.3" d="M43,10C83,10,83,25,123,25" stroke="rgb(140, 86, 75)" stroke-width="1.5"></path><path class="markmap-link" data-depth="3" data-path="1.3.4" d="M181,25C221,25,221,25,261,25" stroke="rgb(148, 103, 189)" stroke-width="1.5"></path><path class="markmap-link" data-depth="4" data-path="1.3.4.5" d="M320,25C360,25,360,12.5,400,12.5" stroke="rgb(148, 103, 189)" stroke-width="1.5"></path><path class="markmap-link" data-depth="4" data-path="1.3.4.6" d="M320,25C360,25,360,37.5,400,37.5" stroke="rgb(148, 103, 189)" stroke-width="1.5"></path><g data-depth="4" data-path="1.3.4.6" transform="translate(400, 17.5)" class="markmap-node"><line x1="-1" x2="61" y1="20" y2="20" stroke="rgb(148, 103, 189)" stroke-width="1.5"></line><foreignObject class="markmap-foreign" x="8" y="0" width="43" height="20" style="opacity: 1;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Step3</div></foreignObject></g><g data-depth="4" data-path="1.3.4.5" transform="translate(400, -7.5)" class="markmap-node"><line x1="-1" x2="60" y1="20" y2="20" stroke="rgb(148, 103, 189)" stroke-width="1.5"></line><foreignObject class="markmap-foreign" x="8" y="0" width="42" height="20" style="opacity: 1;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">2step</div></foreignObject></g><g data-depth="3" data-path="1.3.4" transform="translate(261, 5)" class="markmap-node"><line x1="-1" x2="61" y1="20" y2="20" stroke="rgb(148, 103, 189)" stroke-width="1.5"></line><circle stroke-width="1.5" cx="59" cy="20" r="6" stroke="rgb(148, 103, 189)" fill="var(--markmap-circle-open-bg)"></circle><foreignObject class="markmap-foreign" x="8" y="0" width="43" height="20" style="opacity: 1;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Step2</div></foreignObject></g><g data-depth="2" data-path="1.3" transform="translate(123, 5)" class="markmap-node"><line x1="-1" x2="60" y1="20" y2="20" stroke="rgb(140, 86, 75)" stroke-width="1.5"></line><circle stroke-width="1.5" cx="58" cy="20" r="6" stroke="rgb(140, 86, 75)" fill="var(--markmap-circle-open-bg)"></circle><foreignObject class="markmap-foreign" x="8" y="0" width="42" height="20" style="opacity: 1;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">1step</div></foreignObject></g><g data-depth="2" data-path="1.2" transform="translate(123, -25)" class="markmap-node"><line x1="-1" x2="61" y1="20" y2="20" stroke="rgb(255, 127, 14)" stroke-width="1.5"></line><foreignObject class="markmap-foreign" x="8" y="0" width="43" height="20" style="opacity: 1;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Step1</div></foreignObject></g><g data-depth="1" data-path="1" transform="translate(0,-10)" class="markmap-node"><line x1="-1" x2="45" y1="20" y2="20" stroke="rgb(31, 119, 180)" stroke-width="2"></line><circle stroke-width="1.5" cx="43" cy="20" r="6" stroke="rgb(31, 119, 180)" fill="var(--markmap-circle-open-bg)"></circle><foreignObject class="markmap-foreign" x="8" y="0" width="27" height="20" style="opacity: 1;"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">test</div></foreignObject></g></g></svg>

I have tried several plugins and also tried the gutenberg embedding block, advanced iframe plugin and so on... But the SVG doesnt seem to behave like a regular SVG when im using the plugins. I also tried to use a html file in a folder on the server and then embed it manually in the post as an iframe, that works in preview but as soon as i publish it just breaks.
Any ideas? My preferred solution is to be able to use it as a featured post image but im glad for anything at this stage that can help me display the SVG or embed the HTML properly =)
Its quite big the mindmap so i need to be able to pan/zoom around in the embedding/img.

Some recommendations: 1. please take the time to get familiar with SO snippets (actually you could have pasted it right away into the snippet editor) – running snippets will "skyrocket" your chances to get a  useful answer. 2. be specific about the used libraries/frameworks. This is foremost important because there are a lot of those sharing very similar project names. 3. Consider to split your question into separate tasks: 3.1 how to get a robust rendering 3.2. how to get it in wordpress - circumventing limitations (not sure if <foreignObject> is accepted at all when uploading.
